# Junit test becomes broken when I change a way to initialize Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito, junit5

```
public class DummyTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private TestService service;
    @Mock
    private TestRepository repository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        when(repository.findAllByQuery("")).thenReturn(List.of());
        List<String> entities = service.findAllByQuery("test");

        verify(repository, times(1)).findAllByQuery(anyString());
    }
}

class TestService {

    private TestRepository repository;

    public List<String> findAllByQuery(String query) {
        return repository.findAllByQuery(query);
    }
}

class TestRepository {

    public List<String> findAllByQuery(String query) {
        return List.of("");
    }
}
```

The test above successfully passed when I do `Mockito` initialization via `@BeforeEach` annotation.
After, I tried to remove `@BeforeEach` annotation and initialize `Mockito` with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` and the test failed due to:

`org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException`:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 
Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):
  1. -> at DummyTest.testMe(DummyTest.java:33)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings or use 'lenient' strictness. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.
```

Could you please explain to me, why I got so different test execution results? Technically, I have just changed the way to initialize Mockito and that all.

Answer (score 0):

`@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` and `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` configures Mockito in a little different way.

When you use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` additionally configures "strictness" of Mockito with default value `STRICT_STUBS`.

Which means you have to change the configuration of you stubs like this:

```java
    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        when(repository.findAllByQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(List.of());
        List<String> entities = service.findAllByQuery("test");

        verify(repository, times(1)).findAllByQuery(anyString());
    }
```

or even like this:

```java
    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        when(repository.findAllByQuery(eq("test"))).thenReturn(List.of());
        List<String> entities = service.findAllByQuery("test");

        verify(repository, times(1)).findAllByQuery(anyString());
    }
```